# Should FAQ topics be tagged as discussions?

Tags: discussion

[Triggered by a mild protest by another user over at a meta-question which was uninvolved in this issue.]

All meta-questions must be tagged one of:

- [bug](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bug)
- [feature-request](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/feature-request)
- [discussion](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/discussion)
- [support](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/support)

FAQ questions are not bugs, feature requests or requests for support. They are normally tagged [discussion](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/discussion)

The protest was that they were not discussions, either, because all the messy discussion was cleared away by moderators to keep the FAQ question clear for new users.

How should we resolve this dilemma?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Strictly-speaking, they *should* be [support](/questions/tagged/support) - the purpose is to answer support questions.

That said, some of them begin life as [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion)s, and never quite make it out. If you're taking the time to clean them up while [faq](/questions/tagged/faq)ing them (removing non-canonical answers/discussions, formatting, etc.) then retagging as [support](/questions/tagged/support) would be a good idea.